# How to change the icon of hamburger in different fragment in android using ActionBarDrawerToggle v7 and toolbar v7

Tags: android, android-actionbar, fragment, navigation-drawer, hamburger-menu

It is taking the default icon of navigation in hamburger(grey icon) .

```
mDrawerToggle=new ActionBarDrawerToggle(MainActivity.this,mDrawerLayout,toolbar,R.string.drawer_open,R.string.drawer_open)
    {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);

            invalidateOptionsMenu();
            mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
            mDrawerList.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
            isItemClicked = false;
        }

    };

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());
}
```